# Counting number of cells which can see each cell in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, dem

For each cell in a DEM I'd like to count the number of cells which can see it (i.e. direct line of sight).

Can anyone explain how to do this in QGIS?

Comment: I see this https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ViewshedAnalysis/ and this: http://madchuckle.blogspot.com/2010/10/visibility-analysis-plugin-vap-for-qgis.html

Comment: There is also a GRASS tool **r.los** (los = line of sight) which might be useful, I never used this so can't tell you much.

Answer (score 2):

The [viewshed analysis](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ViewshedAnalysis/) plugin will help you, but I have never tried it with the cumul of all pixels (this would need as many tests as you have pixels, so it might become VERY heavy if you have a large DEM). However, it can take a set of points as inputs for the analysis in order to have the number of points that can be seen (or that can see your pixel). With a dense regular grid of points, you should get what you need.

(select binary viewshed + cumulative)